# Vue iVew menu does not reflect router status like router-link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iview

Started with iView Components for Vue and have some issues with menu component. 
The menu component work as described on [iView homepage](https://www.iviewui.com/components/menu-en) except, it does not reflect the real router status like `<router-link>` do. Entering a route in browser address bar does not mark corresponding menu item as active. This behaviour occur also when redirection a route.

Does anyone has an idea how to handle this?

Here my source template using menu items:

```
<Menu mode="horizontal" :theme="theme1" active-name="1">
  <MenuItem name="1" to="/">Home</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem name="2" to="/about">About</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem name="3" 
            v-if="!isAuthenticated" 
            @click.native="handleAuth()">Signin</MenuItem>
   <Submenu name="3" v-if="isAuthenticated">
     <MenuItem name="3-1">Profile</MenuItem>
     <MenuItem name="3-2"
               @click.native="handleLogout()">Logout</MenuItem>
   </Submenu>
</Menu>
```

And my router definition:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'
import Notfound from './views/Notfound.vue'
import store from './store'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue'),
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/notfound',
      name: 'notfound',
      component: Notfound
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // check if authenticated by jwt from store or localstorage
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)

  if (!to.matched.length) {
    next('/notfound')
    return
  }

  if (requiresAuth && !store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
    next({ path: '/' })
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

export default router
```

Be happy about any hint. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found workaround for this issue.

iView Menu has actually no possibilities to detect the $route changes automatically. Accept we set a watcher for the $router. Think this is not a fine solution, because we have to handle route changes manually.

Much easier and more flexible is to use iView menu CSS classes on `<router-link>` component and set the `linkActiveClass` and `linkExactActiveClass` router property to use iview class.

The source will then look like this:
HTML Template with `<router-link>` component

```
<nav>
  <router-link class="ivu-menu-item" to="/" exact>Root</router-link>
  <router-link class="ivu-menu-item" to="/about">About</router-link>
  <router-link class="ivu-menu-item" to="/profile">Profile</router-link>
</nav>
```

And the router definition:

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  linkActiveClass: 'ivu-menu-item-active',
  linkExactActiveClass: 'ivu-menu-item-active',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue'),
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/signin',
      name: 'signin',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "signin" */ './views/Sign.vue')
    }, {
      path: '/notfound',
      name: 'notfound',
      component: Notfound
    }
  ]
})
```

The result looks like iView Menu component but use the functionality of `<router-link>` component.